# Create Mobile Apps with Flash for iPhone and Android with Embedded browser

Tags: iphone, android, browser, embed, multiplatform

**EDIT:** 
*See my answer*

I saw some interesting frameworks to build applications for mobile platforms like Android and iPhone with HTML and Javascript so you can use your current web-development skills without learning a new platform language. That's very interesting because you can write just ONE application for many platforms. Very easy to maintain.

But, you cannot sell it in the App stores, so I’m wondering if it is possible to use an embedded webbrowser in the application that loads an external/included html file.

I have seen that it is possible to create Android and iPhone apps with flash, that's is easy, so i want to create a simple 'host' application that only loads content and I can use it over and over again to distribute a new app.

So the question is, is it possible to create a simple app with flash that embeds a webbrowser to load a html file?

When it is possible, next question is, it possible to communicate with the embedded webbrowser? Also a question is, will Apple allow such application in it app store?

I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: Just wondering, what are some of these platforms you're talking about? I have to develop some Android apps and would be interested to know what you're found. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all this time i got the answer.

Phonegap uses a WebView to display the HTML content. It is a compiled native App with embedded WebView.

Apple accepts phonegap generated applications but it still not sure if it made it to the AppStore, it depends on what you doing with it. I think simple apps will made it. See also: http://www.phonegap.com/faq

**EDIT/UPDATE:**
I tried allot of tools/solutions to create crossplatform apps but all of these seem to do the same thing: It's a executable for the specific platform with an embedded browser. None of them compiles HTML to native code.

Flash (Builder) is something different, it requires AIR (can be compiled into the executable). When you using a WebView (only) with Flash, it is overkill because in fact you do not need AIR to display the HTML in a WebView. I think it is better to use phonegap to 'compile' the executable.

Comment: Scott Hanselman has a good podcast on someone actually using Phonegap to make their Android & iPhone app.  Here's a link if you're interested:  http://www.hanselminutes.com/304/making-your-first-phonegap-application-with-peter-mourfield

Comment: Ah, thanks - very nice info. I think PhoneGap creates a native app with a WebView wrapper. It is similar to a executable with a webbrowser in it so how it looks and works depends on the embedded browser.

I think phonegap includes some extra native interface (to comunicate with the os) to use the camera etc.
Is this a right conclusion?

Comment: that is my understanding also.  I'm experimenting with jQuery Mobile, HTML5, & PhoneGap.  Although I haven't gotten to the point of uploading it to PhoneGapBuild.  I don't have (and don't want) a MAC so PhoneGapBuild is my only option for iPhone development.

Comment: I got a strange feeling with the WebView thing, it seems that it is used in many cross platform products. It was just an idea to do it this way but i think using a WebView is the only way to get 'native' cross platform. I asked this question a couple of months ago and now i discover that allot of commercial tools do the same thing to go cross platform. We only need to get native to get your app in the appstore. Strange conclusion. In fact it is a webapp in a native wrapper. Tools advertising that your HTML5 will be 'compiled' to a native app is false, because performance same as in browser.

Comment: You talk about PhoneGapBuild. The idea is similar to what i found two days before: http://www.appsgeyser.com/ but only for android.

Answer (score 0):

In a very strict sense, yes, you can make an app that is just a simple `WebView` wrapper pointing to your web-hosted app.

This is usually frowned upon though in the android market community, and i'm fairly positive such an app won't make it through Apple's closed-doors decision committee.

Answer (score 0):

On the iPhone, if your app only consist of a UIWebView it is very likely that you app is going to be rejected. What you could do is ask your users to bookmark your webapp adding an icon to the home screen. Think [Basecamp for iPhone](http://basecamphq.com/mobile).

Comment: No, it won't be rejected - see [this app](http://itunes.apple.com/br/app/gymdeck/id424563164?mt=8)

Comment: Apple hasn't been consistent on their rejections. It is very possible that Apple rejects your app for going against one of their rules that an approved app doesn't follow.

http://www.edibleapple.com/rejection-of-ca-ching-app-highlights-apples-inconsistent-app-store-guidelines/
http://www.tuaw.com/2009/08/22/distinctions-without-differences-apples-inconsistent-app-store/